# Code Optimization issue

Tags: android, function, optimization, switch-statement, coding-style

I am doing some code changes in Android development to make my coding more accurate.
I have 7 TextViews in my layout for all week days, i have done find view by id for all those TextViews.

The requirement is that only one TextView should remain selected at a time when user click anyone from that 7 TextViews.

So, i have some repeated code as below, check it out :

```
 case R.id.txt_sunday:
            if (Prefrences.getBooleanValue(mContext, D_SUN)) {
                doUnSelect(D_SUN, mTxtSunday);
            } else {
                Prefrences.setBooleanValue(mContext, HH_FILTER, true);
                selectedDay = "0";
                Prefrences.setBooleanValue(mContext, D_SUN, true);
                Prefrences.setBooleanValue(mContext, D_MON, false);
                Prefrences.setBooleanValue(mContext, D_TUE, false);
                Prefrences.setBooleanValue(mContext, D_WED, false);
                Prefrences.setBooleanValue(mContext, D_THR, false);
                Prefrences.setBooleanValue(mContext, D_FRI, false);
                Prefrences.setBooleanValue(mContext, D_SAT, false);
                mTxtSunday.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAppDefault);
                mTxtSunday.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                mTxtMonday.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                mTxtMonday.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                mTxtTuesday.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                mTxtTuesday.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                mTxtWednesday.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                mTxtWednesday.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                mTxtThrusday.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                mTxtThrusday.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                mTxtFriday.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                mTxtFriday.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                mTxtSaturday.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                mTxtSaturday.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            }
            break;
```

As, you can see in above code.. I have taken a switch case for handling click of all my seven TextViews, above case is for SUNDAY.
So Now, you might get idea that I have done same for the remaining days form Monday to Saturday. correct.

Now, i have to optimize my else part as I have optimized my if part in above code.

How ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `mTxtSunday` in your code, button,textview?

Comment: ya, actually its TextView.. But, it doesn't matter. concept is same for button and textview. sry for my mistake. Consider it as TextView.

Comment: And what is `D_SUN` is it `int`, `String` something?

Comment: Its Constant, a String. in created Prefrence class : public static final String D_SUN = "D_SUN";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a class:

**WeekDay**

```
public class WeekDay {

final String key;
final TextView textView;
final Context context;

public WeekDay(Context context, String key, TextView textView) {
    this.key = key;
    this.textView = textView;
    this.context = context;
}

public void select() {
    textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
    Prefrences.setBooleanValue(context, key, true);

}


public void unSelect() {
    textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAppDefault);
    Prefrences.setBooleanValue(context, key, false);
}}
```

Then in your main class init an array with the WeekDays

`WeekDays[] days=new WeekDays[]{new WeekDay(context,D_SUN,sundeyTxt),new WeekDay(context,D_MON,mondeyTxt),...}`

and in your else you can call:

```
for(int i=0;i<days.length;i++){ if(i==0)days[i].select();else days[i].unselect();}
```

Hope you get the idea...